# What is the nice way in ruby to parse 2020-W9 dates

Tags: ruby, alexa-skills-kit

From Alexa I am getting week format like this `2020-W9`, but for ruby `Date.parse` I need it in this format `2020-W09`. 
I am wondering what is the nice ruby solution for that. If there is some internal library which can convert `W9` to `W09` or some one line function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the exact format, you should use [`strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) instead of `parse`. It's more specific and parses values without leading zero just fine:

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime('2020-W9', '%Y-W%W')
#=> #<Date: 2020-03-02 ((2458911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

`%Y` is a 4-digit year and `%W` the week number for weeks starting on Monday. There's also `%U` if your weeks start on a Sunday:

```
Date.strptime('2020-W9', '%Y-W%U')
#=> #<Date: 2020-03-01 ((2458910j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

or `%G` / `%V` for ISO 8601 based dates: (this seems to be the one `parse` returns)

```
Date.strptime('2020-W9', '%G-W%V')
=> #<Date: 2020-02-24 ((2458904j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```rb
"2020-W9".sub(/(?<=-W)\d\z/, '0\0')  # => "2020-W09"
"2020-W19".sub(/(?<=-W)\d\z/, '0\0') # => "2020-W19"
```

It will only put a `0` before the number if it's a single digit.

Comment: Thanks, this works too, but I like more `Date.strptime ` approach

Comment: @MarkusBerg, if in the end you want to parse it as a date, then the `Date.strptime` approach makes more sense! :)

Comment: yes, I changed in my code `Date.parse` to `Date.strptime`. This is exactly what I was looking for. But Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
irb(main):003:0> "2020-W9".gsub('-W','-W0')
"2020-W09"

irb(main):010:0> fdate = (date.match(/-W(\d+)/)[1].to_i <= 9)? date.gsub('-W','-W0') : date
"2020-W09"
irb(main):011:0> date = "2020-W10"
"2020-W10"
irb(main):012:0> fdate = (date.match(/-W(\d+)/)[1].to_i <= 9)? date.gsub('-W','-W0') : date
"2020-W10"
irb(main):013:0>
```

Comment: what if it would be `"2020-W10"`?